# Why does the addActionListener method need these stages?

Tags: java, arguments, actionlistener, system.exit

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

I am learning Java and saw the above code.
I can't understand why the `addActionlisetner` method needs `Actionlistener` for  the argument.
Isn't it simpler to just use `System.exit(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the the [API Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) as reference to find the answer of your question.

> public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)
>
> Adds an ActionListener to the button.
>
> Parameters:
>
> l - the ActionListener to be added

For example, the concrete class [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener%28java.awt.event.ActionListener%29) inherited the method `addActionListener(ActionListener l)` from the class javax.swing.AbstractButton.

When you do :

```
new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You're creating an instance of an [anonymous subclass](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) of ActionListener.

**ActionListener is an interface made for receiving actions events.**

The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) says:

> The class that is interested in processing an action event implements this interface, and the object created with that class is registered with a component, using the component's addActionListener method. When the action event occurs, that object's actionPerformed method is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

That's how Java works. You need to pass an instance of an anonymous class to the `addActionListener()` method (it's a listener after all).

This is how you do things using Java 7 or older. But, using *Java 8*, you can use a lambda expression to shorten the code (since [**ActionListener**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) is a *functional interface*):

```
// You can do this
b.addActionListener((ActionEvent) ae -> System.exit(0));
// or this
b.addActionListener((ActionEvent) ae -> {
    System.exit(0);
});
// or even better, this
b.addActionListener(ae -> System.exit(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument of addActionListener specifies an instance of the event handler class as listener of a component (in this case '**b**')
Passing an instance of the anonymouos class 'ActionListener' or an instance of your own class (b.actionListener(this)), both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, The `actionPerformed()` method in `ActionListener` class is called when you press a button.

You cannot have `b.addActionListener(System.exit(0));` because `System.exit(0)` is a method. In Java, you can't pass methods as arguments but you can pass classes.